# Trim blank newlines from string in Ruby 

Tags: ruby, trim

I have a string of four blank lines which all up makes eight lines in total in the following:

```
str = "aaa\n\n\nbbb\n\nccc\ddd\n"
```

I want to return this all in one line. The output should be like this on a single line:

```
aaabbbcccddd
```

I used various trim functions to get the output but still I am failing.

What method do I have to use here?

Comment: To clarify: Do you want all line breaks removed, or just lines that are blank?

Comment: (I think weepos was asking that you click the check mark next to Matchu's answer, so that it turns green.  This marks this answer as the accepted solution, gives Matchu bonus points, give you bonus points, and gives a clear visual indicator to all that the problem has an answer)

Answer (score 13):

The Ruby (and slightly less Perl-ish) way:

```
new_str = str.delete "\n"
```

...or if you want to do it in-place:

```
str.delete! "\n"
```

Comment: ...I somehow only just now noticed this answer, and it's definitely cleaner. Nice work xD

Answer (score 11):

```
str.gsub(/\n/,'')
```

Comment: Wow Its working this is what I wanted ..amazing.., I struggled lot, you guys solved it within 1minute. Thank you very much. I’m new to ruby language as well as to this site. Hopefully I’ll be able to solve my ruby related questions from all of you. Thanks again

Comment: There's a little check mark next to it - that's what you click when you're using an answer ^_^

Answer (score 1):

```
> str = "aaa\n\n\nbbb\n\nccc\ddd\n" 
=> "aaa\n\n\nbbb\n\ncccddd\n"
> str.gsub("\n", "")
=> "aaabbbcccddd"
```