# Ruby remove empty lines from string

Tags: ruby, string

How do i remove empty lines from a string?
I have tried
some_string = some_string.gsub(/^$/, "");

and much more, but nothing works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby : Trim New blank lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040390/ruby-trim-new-blank-lines)

Comment: it's not a duplicate. that title is *very* misleading

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Remove blank lines:

```
str.gsub /^$\n/, ''
```

Note: unlike some of the other solutions, this one actually removes blank lines and not line breaks :)

```
>> a = "a\n\nb\n"
=> "a\n\nb\n"
>> a.gsub /^$\n/, ''
=> "a\nb\n"
```

Explanation: matches the start `^` and end `$` of a line with nothing in between, followed by a line break.

Alternative, more explicit (though less elegant) solution:

```
str.each_line.reject{|x| x.strip == ""}.join
```

Comment: It depends on the definition of _elegant_; one might argue that the more explicit solution is the more elegant! :)

Answer (score 13):

squeeze (or squeeze!) does just that - without a regex.

```
str.squeeze("\n")
```

Comment: @janechii `hello \n` is not ` hello followed by a blank line, it is " hello" followed by a line ending.

Answer (score 4):

Replace multiple newlines with a single one:

```
fixedstr = str.gsub(/\n\n+/, "\n")
```

or

```
str.gsub!(/\n\n+/, "\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try to replace all occurrences of 2 or more line breaks with just one:

```
my_string.gsub(/\n{2,}/, '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Originally**

```
some_string = some_string.gsub(/\n/,'')
```

**Updated**

```
some_string = some_string.gsub(/^$\n/,'')
```