# Remove blank rows from CSV file

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file that contains blank rows like this:

```
row A

row B
row C


row D
```

How should I proceed to remove those blank rows to have:

```
row A
row B     
row C  
row D
```

I found many topics on this subject for other languages but none in Ruby.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339292/ruby-remove-empty-lines-from-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three simple steps:

```
data = File.read('data.csv')                       # Read the file
cleaned = data.gsub(/^$\n/, '')                    # Remove blank lines, from [1]
File.open('out.csv', 'w') { |f| f.write(cleaned) } # Write the cleaned data
```

[1] [Remove empty lines from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339292/ruby-remove-empty-lines-from-string)

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to delete the blank lines, just skip them:

```
require "csv" 

CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv", skip_blanks: true) do |row|
  # handle row, it won't be blank
end
```